# bootstrap tab inside sharepoint visual part

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint, tabs

I have created a SharePoint visual web part which contains bootstrap tabs.
Everything is working fine,however when I select a tab, the content is displayed but the tab isn't set to active unless I double click on the tab item.
Any Ideas?

Thx,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to mention that I was using Angularjs.
However, to make it work I had to use Angular ui  Bootstrap.